# Molokai colors off in terminal

Tags: terminal, gvim, colorscheme

I've recently switched to the molokai color scheme and I've noticed that the colors look different than in gVim. I remember that I spent ages trying to get my terminal-vim to properly display the 256-color version of my previous theme.

Is the terminal-version of monokai supposed to look like the following or is there something off here (terminal without tmux on the left, gVim on the right).

[image: Terminal without tmux on the left, gvim on the right]

Comment: The [README also mentions this](https://github.com/tomasr/molokai): *"256-Color terminals are also supported, though there are some differences with the Gui version."* ...